# filter dataframe from external file

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

i want to filter my dataframe from an external file. 
this is how my dataframe look like:

```
val Insert=Append_Ot.filter(col("Name2").equalTo("brazil") || col("Name2").equalTo("france") || col("Name2").equalTo("algeria")|| col("Name2").equalTo("tunisia") || col("Name2").equalTo("egypte")  )
```

The number of countries that i want to filter them is changeable, so created an external this file:

```
 1  brazil
 2  france
 3  algeria
 4  tunisia
 5  egypte
```

i want to create UDF to filter my dataframe from this file.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question. Would you care reviewing it ?

Comment: i update my question, i hope its clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `Seq` from the file with which you want to filter. 
Something that looks like this:

```
val l = List("Brasil", "Algeria", "Tunisia", "Egypt")
```

You can use `textFile` method. Suppose your file contains:

```
1 Algeria
2 Tunisia
3 Brasil
4 Egypt
```

You can use:

```
val countries = sc.textFile("hdfs://namenode/user/cloudera/file").map(_.split(" ")(1)).collect
```

which will give you:

```
countries : Array[String] = Array(Algeria, Tunisia, Brasil, Egypt)
```

And then, use the `isin` function on your column `Name2`

```
val Insert = Append_Ot.where($"Name2".isin( countries : _* ) )
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i got a empty dataframe

Comment: compare the contents of you array. If you don't have any of those columns in your dataframe, then you will get an empty dataframe.

Comment: yes i have them, i use a text file that give me `countries : Array[String] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)`

Comment: I used the wrong index. changed the code. Can you check now and see if you are getting countries in that array?

Comment: I already changed the index and i got the countries. But i still have an empty datarame too.

Comment: it might be due to spelling mismatch or case letters. philantrovert's answer is perfect. you just have to edit some parts . for more detial you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080620/empty-dataframe-with-isin-function/45081342#45081342