# How to use isin function with values from text file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to filter a dataframe using an external file.

This is how I use the filter now:

```
val Insert = Append_Ot.filter(
  col("Name2").equalTo("brazil") ||
  col("Name2").equalTo("france") ||
  col("Name2").equalTo("algeria") ||
  col("Name2").equalTo("tunisia") ||
  col("Name2").equalTo("egypte"))
```

Instead of using hardcoded string literals, I'd like to create an external file with the values to filter by.

So I create this file:

```
val filter_numfile = sc.textFile("/user/zh/worskspace/filter_nmb.txt")
  .map(_.split(" ")(1))
  .collect
```

This gives me:

```
filter_numfile: Array[String] = Array(brazil, france, algeria, tunisia, egypte)
```

And then, I use `isin` function on `Name2` column.

```
val Insert = Append_Ot.where($"Name2".isin(filter_numfile: _*))
```

But this gives me an empty dataframe. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just adding some information to philantrovert answer in [filter dataframe from external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078066/filter-dataframe-from-external-file)

His answer is perfect but there might be some case unmatch so you will have to check for case mismatch as well

---

**tl;dr** Make sure that the letters use consistent case, i.e. they are all in upper or lower case. Simply use `upper` or `lower` standard functions.

---

lets say you have input file as

```
1 Algeria
2 tunisia
3 brazil
4 Egypt
```

you read the text file and change all the countries to lowercase as

```
val countries = sc.textFile("path to input file").map(_.split(" ")(1).trim)
  .collect.toSeq
val array = Array(countries.map(_.toLowerCase) : _*)
```

Then you have your dataframe

```
val Append_Ot = sc.parallelize(Seq(("brazil"),("tunisia"),("algeria"),("name"))).toDF("Name2")
```

where you apply following condition

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val Insert = Append_Ot.where(lower($"Name2").isin(array : _* ))
```

you should have output as

```
+-------+
|Name2  |
+-------+
|brazil |
|tunisia|
|algeria|
+-------+
```

The empty dataframe might be due to spelling mismatch too.